# Where are environment variables for 'https_proxy' set in Windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code it picks a certain proxy that I use at my workplace and it’s totally messing everything up now since Gradle cannot sync correctly as it tries to connect through the proxy.

The settings in Visual Studio Code are as below. What are the htps_proxy environment variables?

```
// The proxy setting to use. If not set will be taken from the http_proxy and
   https_proxy environment variables
  "http.proxy": "",
```

Comment: Re *"htps_proxy environment variables"*: Do you mean *"https_proxy environment variables"*?

Comment: Re *"The settings in Visual Studio Code"*: Where exactly? What file?

Comment: What do you mean by the question? Are there two environment variables, `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`? Can you elaborate? Preferably, by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51574482/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: What do you need to mess with (global?) environment variables if it can be set in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

See *[How to set the path and environment variables in Windows](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)*.

Here's a guide on how you can access Windows environment variables. From there, you can delete the environment variables that interfere with your build.

Comment: Hi. I get this, but where are the https_variables. According to VS code it is supposed to check for a proxy and if the proxy set is null    _"http.proxy": "",_  it picks one from the environment variables. I need to find that https_variables and delete it I just don't know where they are located